# How can I cluster the points of the same states/provinces in Tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have a csv file contains some statistics data, and each row represent a city.

I want to visualize them using Tableau and map them to the real world map. However, I am only able to put them onto the map as points or some other shapes, like the picture below:

[image: my]

What I really want is like the picture below:
[image: want]

I am able to figure out that this is because I have more than one point in a state/province, but I don't know how to sum these points and make them into one point that has their total value using Tableau.

Is there any possible solution for me? Thanks!

Comment: Does your csv also have a 'state' / 'province' column? If so, then you can add that variable to the map and set it to 'sum' in the marks card.

Comment: @Niels Henkens, Thanks, but I only have a 'country' column, but I will try to find their states.

Comment: How are the city names formatted? E.g. “San Francisco” or “San Francisco, Ca”? In the last case, you could split the city names by “,” to also get the state abbreviation. I don’t know if Tableau would recognize “Ca” directly as California, but otherwise it would be easy to find a file with a list of state abbreviations and names. You could then join this to your current file to get the states.

Comment: @Niels Henkens Only US cities have their states column, I have to find a way to fill this column for cities of other countries.

Comment: Maybe the Google Maps API can help you here (But I don’t have any personal experience with it).